# Assigning image from assets returns nil

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)   
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named:"SignIn")
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

SignIn is name of my imageSet created in assets

Comment: Is it a `.png` file? Otherwise you'll have to add the file name extension.

Comment: It is .jpeg file. I have removed images from asset and again added it.And it is working now. But I am not getting why it was showing nil previously

Comment: Looks like a bug in Xcode. Not the only one.

Answer (score 3):

Try using image literals. They are type checked and validated to be not `nil` at compile time.

Use `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "SignIn")` instead of `UIImage(named: "SignIn")` and check what the compiler says.

Chances are that you either mistyped the name, used wrong case (iOS is case sensitive) or the file is a `jpg` and has weird usage in `UImage(named:)`

Comment: You saved my day, Image name is "Forest.jpeg" and i renamed it to "Forest.jpg", it worked, thanks a lot